# Convert error string to raw html in python code

Tags: python, html, flask

With Flask-wtf I want to display an error message, which should contain a HTML link to the existing profile. I need to convert the built link as string to HTML, which will be appended to the error message.

Here is an excerpt from the code:

```
class AddBookmarkForm(Form):
   # Some Python code to define the form


def validate_bookmark_url(self, field):

    if the bookmark_url exists:
        bookmark_id = fetching the bookmarks id
        link = '<a href="bookmark/' + str(bookmark_id) + '">Show bookmark?</a>'
        raise ValidationError('User already exists. ' + link)
```

The ouput is just a string like 'User already saved. <a href="bookmark/123456'>Show bookmark?</a>'.
How do I convert this to executable HTML inside the Python script?

Comment: I don't believe raising an exception is what you want. You should be using the HTTP error codes (only if one fits) and returning an HTML page. Raising an exception will stop the dev server and return a 500 on a production server.

Comment: It's not a classic Python exception. If the user wants to register for example and the username is already taken, Flask-WTF allows me to render a little error message next to the input field as raw HTML.

Flask-WTF generates all the HTML associated to the form and includes this in the template itself. The raised error message/exception is only raw HTML.

Inside the the form in html (as example):

    `<input type="text" name="username">
    <span class="error-class">My raised error message a HTML</span>`

Comment: Perhaps this will be of some use, http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/validators.html#custom-validators

Comment: In the docs of your link I saw that ValidationError accepts more parameters than the message. This way I could send the link with the error message, but I am using the quick_form() method of the extension Flask-Bootstrap to generate all the Boostrap related HTML. [Look here](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html?highlight=quick_form#forms)

Comment: Beware of XSS. That is, wait until someone registers username `0"></a><a href="www.maliciouswebsite.com`.

Comment: A predefinded validator let me check this py passing a regex pattern as parameter. **By the way, I changed the scenario a bit to make it more logically but the result is the same. Take a look below.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a few suggestions here even though I am not directly answering your exact question. The reason is that I think you should not do it the way you are trying to:

1) If a user already exists, then why do you even need to show them the URL ? Just say "This user already exists". The user who exists should already know their URL. Also, I am assuming that the url /userid needs a login first.

2) But lets say that you still want to tell the user to login, then I would rather change the code to this:

```
 if the user_exists:
    return redirect(url_for(login)) # assuming you have a view function for login.
```

This way, you are just asking them to login which anyway is what the end goal is in case user exists already.

This in my opinion will be a better way to do it. You don't need to worry about passing the URL in error message string. Error messages should just be simple strings as a good practice. No need to complicate them.

Comment: I should may change the example: Imagine I store a Bookmark inside a database. The user wants to enter the same URL (without knowing it) again. In this scenario, I could give this little hint to the existing bookmark with a link.

I did tried this before with flash(), but got the same result with the string. My final intention was it to outsource the exception stuff from my view function to the related Form class where the error handling is done by Flask-WTFs custom exception function.

Comment: **I updated the scenario in the question, the process is still the same.**